# angular 8 how to disable button of child component that use multiple times in parent component

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a child component that can be used multiple times in parent component with different action.now How can i disable button that exist in child component when i click on button in parent component.

My child component that can be used multiple times:

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-product',
    template: `<button [disabled]="isDisableButton">select</button>`
})

export class MyCardComponent {
  @Input() isDisableButton = false;
}
```

my parent component html :

```
<div>
   <p>Product Type 1<p>
  <my-product [isDisableButton]="isDisableType1Button"></my-product>
   <button (click)="onType1()">select type 1</button>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Product  Type 2<p>
  <my-product [isDisableButton]="isDisableType2Button"></my-product>
   <button (click)="onType2()">select type 1</button>
</div>
```

my parent component ts :

```
      @Component({
      selector: 'my-parentComponent',
      templateUrl: '..'
    })
    export class PopupDirective {

        isDisableType1Button : boolean;
        isDisableType2Button: boolean;

     onType2(){
        this.isDisableType1Button = true;
        this.isDisableType2Button = false;
         }

    onType1(){
       this.isDisableType2Button = true;
       this.isDisableType1Button = false;
      }

  }
```

this solution is not work correctly

Comment: Can you provide stack-blitz link?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9xyyga?file=src/app/app.component.ts), there's nothing wrong with logic you implemented.

Maybe you missed on your child component the import of `Input` decorator:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Then can you figure out why it's not working? As you can see on the Stackblitz, this is working well.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with component output events, you can read about in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

Below a very clean example to keep it concise:

```
<button (click)="b.disabled = true">trigger component</button>
<button #b>react on trigger</button>
```

The trigger button (acting as your parent component) has a standard output for the click event. The (inline) event handler is taken a template reference (`#b`) to directly manipulate the disabled state.

If you translate this to your example, you should implement an output with the `EventEmitter`.